# How to pg_dump only the INSERT statements without SET / SELECTS / -- Comments in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, dump, pg-dump

My bash code to dump only specific lines of a table:

```
acc_db mydb -c "create table export_table as $1"
mypg_dump -d mydb -a -t export_table --data-only --column-inserts >> /tmp/export_data.sql
acc_db mydb -c "drop table export_table"
sed -i -e 's/export_table/'$table'/g' /tmp/export_data.sql

# where : 
# $1 contains my SELECT statement 
# $table is the actual name of the table I'm interest in
# acc_db is a wrapper to override the pwd insert 
# mydb is ... some db
```

First off, I used to use a grep on the mypg_dump line to get only the INSERT statements - but as I found that multiline fields got grepped away, breaking the sql statement, I had to change it. 
However now I have this kind of output :

```
-- some comment 
-- comment 
*blank lines* 

*various SET statements* 
*SELECT statements* 

INSERT [...]

-- some comments 
*more blank lines*
```

All I need really is the INSERT statement but I can't find any way to get the insert only.

Comment: ... it works, and it's not what I asked

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting multi-line inserts, you'll need to use something a bit more flexible than grep. An example using a perl one-liner:

`perl -wlne 'if (!$current_statement){if (/^\s*INSERT/){if (/;\s*$/) {push @inserts, $_} else {s/\r//g;$current_statement = $_}}} else {$current_statement .= $_;if (/;\s*$/){push @inserts, $current_statement;$current_statement = "";}}}{print for (@inserts)' /tmp/export_data.sql > /tmp/insert_data.sql`

A breakdown of what's happening:

```perl
# - w: use warnings
# - l: loop through input storing each line's contents in $_
# - n: don't print the line after processing
# - e: execute one liner

if (!$current_statement) { # if not in multi-line insert
  if (/^\s*INSERT/) {      # skip if it's not an INSERT statement
    if (/;\s*$/){          # single line insert, push to list
      push @inserts, $_
    } else {               # multi-line insert strip off CR, save line and continue
      s/\r//g;
      $current_statement = $_
    }
  }
} else {                     # continue an multi-line existing multi-line insert
  $current_statement .= $_;  # always append the statement
  if (/;\s*$/){              # if finished, push to @inserts, reset variable
    push @inserts, $current_statement;
    $current_statement = "";
  }
}
}{  # "eskimo kiss": finishes the loop from -n, runs code after processing the files
  print for (@inserts) # print each entry of the inserts array
```